# Custom styles (Arrow, Bg, etc..) on Bootstrap 4 tooltips and Popovers

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, tooltip, popover

I was digging on Bootstrap 4 tooltips and popovers in order to be able on customizing any arrow or background color, text, etc.
This is what I found.
Feel free to add your code or ask for a particular outcome.

Also, I am very interesting on see how looks the popover HTML markup which is missing on [Bootstrap 4 Docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/popovers/)

The codepen I´ve created: https://codepen.io/jaabert/pen/bZJZVp

It´s very important to notice the use of (BTW) !important on

```
.bs-tooltip-top,
.bs-tooltip-right,
.bs-tooltip-left,
.bs-tooltip-bottom {
  background-color: transparent;
  opacity: 1!important;
}
```

Just to override B4 styles, because by default tooltips are not 100% opaque.

Answer (score 0):

I've updated the codepen with the popover html markup, and some solutions, not elegant but simple and effective plain CSS. Also be careful with the style son pseudo-element on "bs-popover-top":

```
      <div class="popover bs-popover-top show" role="tooltip">
        <div class="arrow" style="left: 50%"></div>
        <h3 class="popover-header">Popover header</h3>
        <div class="popover-body">Popover -body</div>
      </div>
```

https://codepen.io/jaabert/pen/bZJZVp